# Recursion inside another recursion - can it still be called a recursion overall?

Tags: python, recursion

To get the 2D list sum using recursion I used one recursion to get single row values and another recursion to get all the row values.

```
def arraysum_row(list, r, c):
    if c==0: return list[r][0]
    else: return list[r][c] + arraysum_row(list, r, c - 1)


def matrix_sum(list,r,c):
    if r==-1: return 0
    else: return (arraysum_row(list,r,c)+matrix_sum(list,r-1,c))


list = [[10, 90,20], [30, 40,50],[100, 10,10]]
x= (matrix_sum(list, len(list)-1, len(list[0])-1))
print(x)
```

Comment: This is a string...

Comment: Is it recursive? Yes. Is it correct? Try it out yourself.

Comment: please read what is [recursion](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion/)